# Combine first sheet of multiple workbooks into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to combine different workbooks into one master Excel workbook:

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "\Users\myname\Documenten\Test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

How would I include only the first worksheet of each workbook into the master workbook?

How would I rename the worksheets to the name of the workbook it comes from?

Comment: There are a couple of characters that are valid in workbook names that are not valid in worksheet names ("[" and "]"), and worksheet names are limited to 31 characters while workbook names can be longer.  So be prepared for errors or other unexpected behaviour if you try to set the worksheet name equal to the workbook name.

Comment: Okay thanks and if I only want to include sheet 1 and 4 of each workbook without changing the name?

Comment: See the answer from user3598756, and just add a line saying `.Worksheets(4).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` after `.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`, and also remove the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).name = .name` line.

Comment: @Sner88, please stick to your current question and go to the end of it. I posted an answer and if it does what your _original_ question asked then please accept it. If  different issues arise then make new posts

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSheets()
    Dim Path As String, fileName As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Path = "\Users\myname\Documenten\Test\"
    fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).name = .name
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn;t work. Now I get the first worksheet of the first workbook and it saves the workbookname as the first sheetname. However I need the first sheets of all workbooks and rename the first sheets of all workbooks into the name of the workbooks themselves. Do you know how to do this? Maybe change the for each statement?

Comment: the code doesn't work as you described in your comment. Rather it 1) opens, one by one, all ".xls" type workbooks in a given folder 2) copies their first worksheet only into the workbook which the macro resides in after its first worksheet 3) rename the newly inserted worksheet as per the "source" workbook name. Which is actually what you asked for.  I tested it. Did you?

Comment: @Sner88, did you get through it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)` line changes the ActiveWorkbook to be the destination workbook.  Which then causes the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` statement to be referring to the "master" workbook.  I think the easiest solution is to include a `.Close` inside the `With` block, and remove the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` statement.

Comment: @YowE3K, were it as you are saying then it'd close "ThisWorkbook" i.e. the workbook the macro itself resides in, which I would have noticed...

Comment: That's exactly what happened when I tried it.  And it left me with the first of the .xls files still open.  (Strictly speaking, it actually gave me a chance to cancel the saving of the macro workbook first, and if I said "cancel" each time then the macro workbook would still be open at the end [with all other workbooks also still open] and the macro workbook would correctly have all the sheets in it.)

Comment: @YowE3K I'm not by my PC to check it, but when testing it worked flawlessly. Maybe we're testing in two different _environments_, though I couldn't guess how. I'll check it again in some 10 hours...

Comment: FWIW, I'm in Win7 with 32-bit Excel 2013.  And, also FWIW, I upvoted your answer yesterday [my yesterday] because I thought it was the exact correct answer, and it was only when I tried running it when I got to work today that I noticed that it was behaving weird.  But, because the OP is also having the same issues (or very similar issues?), it makes me think there **must** be something unexpected happening.

Comment: @YowE3k, I confirm that in my Win7ProSP1 - Microsoft Office Plus Excel 2013 environment the `ActiveWorkbook` stays the opened file from `Workbooks.Open` to `ActiveWorkbook.Close`

Comment: OK, this is getting weirder every second.  I just tried on my home computer (Win10, OfficeProPlus 2010) and it fails.  I copied your exact code, changing only the path statement (to "D:\Data\Temp_20160907\"), saved that file as Book9.xlsm, created three files (Book1.xls, Book2.xls, and Book3.xls) each with a single sheet (Sheet1), all saved to the directory I was using, ensured all workbooks were closed, opened Book9.xlsm, ran the macro, and it copied Book1.xls's Sheet1 to Book9.xlsm, renamed it correctly, then asked whether I wanted to save Book9.xlsm and then closed it.

Comment: @YowE3K maybe your "xlsm" file is in the same folder of "xls" files?

Comment: I just tried moving it to a different directory - same behaviour.  I wasn't expecting that it would match `*.xls`, but I see it does, but it was still processing Book1.xls (the first match of the Dir) when it tried to close Book9.xlsm so that may have caused problems later in the loop but it never had a chance to get to that point.

Comment: FWIW - I see why I was confused about the behaviour of Dir("*.xls") - on my Win7 work computer that will only return the .xls files, but on my Win10 home computer it effectively returns `*.xls*`.  (It's a change to the o/s - I tested in a command window.)

Comment: @YowE3K, thanks for sharing that. I'll check it as soon as I get in touch with a Win10 PC. As for the `ActiveWorkbook` issue I guess we're still on our old _positions_: my code works in my environment while doesn't in yours

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetSheets()
Dim Path As String, fileName As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Path = "\somepath\"
fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    End With
 Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code block. Did you mean to include the first and last lines in your code block? Additionally, code-only answers are discouraged. You should explain how and why this answers the question.